# Ubuntu 16.04 systemd redis issues with ulimit

Tags: ubuntu, redis, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, ulimit

I have been having issues with our new redis server after swapping from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. The configuration of the open files limit using all the guides says to change the /etc/security/limits.conf with the following settings

```
*    soft nofile 65535
*    hard nofile 65535
root soft nofile 65535
root hard nofile 65535
```

And also to add to /etc/pam.d/common-session and /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

I have made all of these changes but redis is still starting up with a file limit of 4096 which under production load we quickly reach max connections.

Answer (score 34):

After much searching I finally found that systemd has a standard limit of 4096 and regardless of what you set at the system level the systemd level will always take precedence. The fix for this is to change the systemd open file limit by editing  /etc/systemd/system.conf and adding the following setting

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536
```

It seems that there are a lot of default settings in systemd which override the system settings so have to be set in systemd

So if its any use for people these are my final settings for a Ubuntu 16.04 server for running production redis.

Edit /etc/systemd/system.conf (sudo nano /etc/systemd/system.conf) and add

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536
```

Edit /etc/security/limits.conf (sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf) and add

```
*    soft nofile 64000
*    hard nofile 64000
root soft nofile 64000
root hard nofile 64000
```

Edit /etc/pam.d/common-session (sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-session) and add

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Edit /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive (sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive) and add

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Edit /etc/rc.local (sudo nano /etc/rc.local) and add

```
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=65535
```

Edit /etc/sysctl.conf (sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf) and add

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 1
```

Edit /etc/rc.local (sudo nano /etc/rc.local) and add

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

Comment: Great answer! DefaultLimitNOFILE is what I was missing

Comment: Thanks Ollie. This addressed all the issues I faced. Perfect.

Comment: Although this is quite old: Would you be able to elaborate on the settings you make as to what they do and why it was needed? I obviously understand that all works together to set number of files effectively, but as someone who is not deep enough in system administration, understanding what all these do is hard.

Comment: Hmmm I'm still getting complaints when I restart Redis :/

Comment: @worp - This was about 2 weeks of Google searches a few years ago, I am not a Linux guru so I did a lot of research then but the reason for each reason I cannot answer in detail now.

Comment: @shaneonabike - Can you give me more details and I can have a look we have a redis server fully up to date running these settings with no issue

Comment: Sure what details do you need...?

Comment: may I ask why did you set in the limits.conf 64000 instead of 65535?

Answer (score 1):

The sysctl values `net.core.somaxconn` and `vm.overcommit_memory` are note related to ulimit or the number of open files.
They are related to:

- `net.core.somaxconn`: will limit the number of opened but not accepted connections.
  https://serverfault.com/questions/518862/will-increasing-net-core-somaxconn-make-a-difference
- `vm.overcommit_memory`: the policy to overcommit memory when physical memory is exausted.
  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting

If your problem is with the limit of opened files (what `ulimit -Sn/-Hn` handles) then I would not suggest to play with this, unless you know exactly what you are doing.