# emfile error running CouchDB on Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, ubuntu-16.04, systemd

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16 and CouchDB 1.6. When my server gets hammered with a ton of connections, I get `emfile` errors in the couch.log. I've seen these errors before and they appear to be related to the System Resource Limits mentioned at https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Performance. I believe my main problem is with `ERL_MAX_PORTS`. I've already increased my ulimit to 40000 (via PAM) and added `export ERL_MAX_PORTS=40000` to /etc/default/couchdb.

Ubuntu 16 uses systemd so I added `Environment="ERL_MAX_PORTS=40000"` to the `[Service]` section in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/couchdb.service, but this does not seem to work.

I even tried modifying /usr/bin/couchdb and adding `env ERL_MAX_PORTS=40000` to the top of the script.

The only thing that appears to work is when I manually run couchdb from the command line, e.g. `$ env ERL_MAX_PORTS=40000 && sudo /usr/bin/couchdb`. This is not an ideal solution and I would rather get this working with systemd.

I was previously running CouchDB 1.5 on Ubuntu 14 and increased my System Resource Limits (see https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Performance) to about 40000 and it was handling many connections without any issues.

Has anyone had any luck solving this problem on Ubuntu 16?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/39506150/2831606 and it was the missing nugget that I needed to get this working.

Specifically, I had to modify /etc/systemd/system.conf and add

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=40000
```

So, to summarize, here are my configurations:

Let 100-couchdb.conf be:

```
#<domain>    <type>    <item>    <value>
couchdb      hard      nofile    40000
couchdb      soft      nofile    40000
*            hard      nofile    40000
*            soft      nofile    40000
root         hard      nofile    40000
root         soft      nofile    40000
```

1) Set up limits via PAM:

```
cp 100-couchdb.conf /etc/security/limits.d/100-couchdb.conf
cp 100-couchdb.conf /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "session    required   pam_limits.so" >> /etc/pam.d/su
```

2) Increase the allowable number of files in systemd

```
echo "DefaultLimitNOFILE=40000" >> /etc/systemd/system.conf
```

3) Increase the number of connections permitted by Erlang via systemd

```
sed -i "s/\[Service\]/\[Service\]\nEnvironment=ERL_MAX_PORTS=40000/g" /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/couchdb.service
```

4) Also increase the number of connections permitted by Erlang (I'm not sure if this is needed as we already configured this via systemd, but it doesn't seem to hurt)

```
echo "export ERL_MAX_PORTS=40000" >> /etc/default/couchdb
```

Note: while running some stress tests, I found that I needed to increase the limits to about 40000 to support 10,000 concurrent connections. I'm guessing this is due to some overhead where multiple files are needed per connection.

Comment: How is that not in the docs somewhere ? You saved me from my own poor configuration of limits !